# Multi parameter curl request Python, Spotify API

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, spotify

I am trying to execute a curl request for the Spotify API. From what I have seen you can use the requests library yet I am not sure how to do it accounting for the Authorization parameter. Below is the curl request-- Any help is much appreciated!

curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/06AKEBrKUckW0KREUWRnvT" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/06AKEBrKUckW0KREUWRnvT", headers={"Authorization": "Bearer {your access token}"})
```

Comment: it's not worked for me and i got below errror
<Response [400]>
what should i do?

Comment: @Alirezaaraby `print(response.text)`